# What is the purpose of the badge logo in a Windows 10 Store application?

Tags: windows-store-apps

When using Visual Studio 2015 to make a Windows 10 Store application, the package manifest (Package.appxmanifest) lets you add a Badge Logo in 5 different resolutions.  What is the Badge Logo for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The badge logo images are used in some tile templates and on lock screen notifications. The badge is the small logo you often see next to a number on smaller tiles, for example showing an unread message count. On larger tiles this will appear in a corner.

See more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh779719.aspx (yes this page is Win8 documentation but still applies.)